# How to assign a static ip for an nginx container using laradock and docker-compose version 3

Tags: docker-compose, laradock

Im using laradock for a local dev environment

I have a case where I have a soap server @ (soap.localhost.com) consuming the WSDL file from the nginx container @ (api.localhost.com) using php-fpm.

the php-fpm container doesn't know the ip address of the nginx container unless I hard code it the php-fpm section of the docker-comopose.yml

```
      extra_hosts:
        - "dockerhost:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
        - "api.localhost.com:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
```

Everytime I restart the containers the nginx container's ip address changes so I need to assign a static ip address somehow so I don't have to keep hardcoding the extra_hosts section continually.

Laradock already defines 2 networks interfaces:

```
networks:
  frontend:
    driver: bridge
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: @StockOverflaw, close but no , its not a duplcaite. Your link is for version 2 and  without laradock and its extra network definitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FINALLY:   Instead of assigning a static IP to the NGINX container and adding the domains to the  extra_hosts: section to the PHP_FPM container.
I have added aliases to the networks section of the NGINX container, like this

```
### NGINX Server #########################################
    nginx:
      build:
        context: ./nginx
        args:
          - PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER=${NGINX_PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER}
          - PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT=${NGINX_PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT}
          - CHANGE_SOURCE=${CHANGE_SOURCE}
      volumes:
        - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}${APP_CODE_CONTAINER_FLAG}
        - ${NGINX_HOST_LOG_PATH}:/var/log/nginx
        - ${NGINX_SITES_PATH}:/etc/nginx/sites-available
        - ${NGINX_SSL_PATH}:/etc/nginx/ssl
      ports:
        - "${NGINX_HOST_HTTP_PORT}:80"
        - "${NGINX_HOST_HTTPS_PORT}:443"
      depends_on:
        - php-fpm 
        - memcached       
      networks:
        frontend:              
        backend:
         aliases:
          - api.localhost.com
```